# Formatting XML tags and Namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

I am working on a requirement that requires a XML to XML transformation. Here is how my input XML file looks like.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:EMPL_ID>009145215</wd:EMPL_ID>
        <wd:EMAIL_ID>abc@abc.com</wd:EMAIL_ID>
        <wd:FIRST_NAME>ABC</wd:FIRST_NAME>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:EMPL_ID>0132321863</wd:EMPL_ID>
        <wd:EMAIL_ID>def@def.com</wd:EMAIL_ID>
        <wd:FIRST_NAME>DEF</wd:FIRST_NAME>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

My required output will be something like.

```
<empltest xmlns='Different Namespace' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
        <LDMEINFO_EMPL tranType='INSERT'>
            <EMPL_ID>text</EMPL_ID>
            <EMIAL_ID>Y</EMAIL_ID>
            <FIRST_NAME>Y</FIRST_NAME>  
    </empltest>
```

The requirement would be editing the tag names(removing wd:)

Is there any way to do that via XSLT. If there is some material where i can look it up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As written, this question is considered off topic.  The simple answer to your question is "yes, XSLT is made for this."  The question about some material on it is too broad - start just by searching your favorite engine for "XSLT tutorial", and then try to ask a more specific question if you get stuck with something specific.

Comment: Also note that `<wd:Report_Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">` lacks a declaration for the used prefix `wd`, so you couldn't even parse that input with an XML parser supporting namespaces.

Comment: Yes, you can transform `XML` using `XSLT`. What is your question?